# Exit value from bash script different when called from Java

Tags: java, bash, shell

I'm executing some scripts from a Java class. There, I execute the scripts and wait for the results. However, when I execute these files, I don't get the real value of exit status from my scripts.

If I execute the scripts like:

```
./relativePath/script.sh
```

And then I print the value:

```
echo $?
```

I **get the correct value**. But since I'm receiving it inside the Java program, I can't just print `$?`, but just receive the exit value using the class `Process` (all correct until here). So I do:

```
Process program;
program = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
                    {file});
        program.waitFor();
        if ( program.exitValue() == 0)
        {
            result = true;
        }
```

But as I said at the title of the question, when I execute the script in this way, I'm not getting the correct exit status value I'm waiting for.

**Why**?

I've tried it with a C compiled program and It works fine, and checked that the output of the exec status in this case is also saved in `$?`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `bash -c command` returns the same exit status as `command`, and it appears that your attempt to run the command directly (which makes more sense) exhibits the same problem (or some problem; the question is not clear on this point). This suggests that the problem is in your code to extract the exit status, rather than with `bash -c`.

Comment: You're right rici. I've updated the post to fit it.

Comment: Have you tried to see if the `program.getErrorStream()` or `program.getOutputStream()` contains any clues?

Comment: I didn't, but If I had, I would find out the same in an easier way: the scripts were being copied with root user, so root owns the files and tomcat had not enough privileges to run them! Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the files were being copied with root user, and since they have `744` as privileges value, tomcat couldn't run them.

Just solved it with:

```
 chown tomcat6:tomcat6 /pathOfScripts/*.sh
```